# AjaxFileUpload SaveAs function

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I use `AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs` in the Submit button function instead of `UploadComplete`?

Here is my code :

```
foreach (string item in filenames)
{
   string filePath = "C:\\Users\\RRR\\Pictures\\" +  item;
   AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);          
}
```

`filenames` is not empty, but I got this error:

File name cannot be null.
Parameter name: sourceFileName

Comment: can you show us the `filenames` variable?

Comment: it 's a list of string        protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
               
            filenames.Add(e.FileName);

        
    }

Comment: so `List<string> filenames = new List<string>(){ "file1.doc", "file2.txt", "file3.jpg" }`

Comment: yes ,  in the end filePath = C:\\Users\\RRR\\Pictures\\file1.doc

Comment: can you set a breakpoint where you set `filePath` and ensure that it has the right value?

Comment: here's the details on how to properly wire it up. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [File name cannot be null error thrown ajaxfileupload (second control on my page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560499/file-name-cannot-be-null-error-thrown-ajaxfileupload-second-control-on-my-page)